# Iterate through and read all appsettings keys in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have got some configuration added in my appsettings.json file of my asp.net core 3.0 web api project and the file looks something like this:

```
{
  "Logging":{..},
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Section1": {
     "Key1": "Value1",
     "Key2": "Value2",
     ....
  }
}
```

I want to iterate through all the keys in this particular section, Section1 and perform some action on them. I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
foreach (var key in ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys)
                {
                    var key = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key1"];
                    // perform some action
                }
```

`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` doesn't contain anything as can be seen in the screenshot below:
[image]

What else do I need to do to make this work?

I have tried `var v = this._configuration.GetSection("Section1").GetSection("Key1");`where `_configuration` is of the type `IConfiguration` and it works as expected. But again, like I mentioned I don't want this, instead I want to iterate through all the list of keys in the appsettings and perform some action on them.

Any help would be great.

Comment: There's no such class in .NET Core

Comment: The [Configuration section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) in the docs explains how to create and load the configuration, how *all* data is converted into key/value pairs, how to find sections and values with `GetSection` or `GetValue` and how to get concrete types from the values

Comment: I have tried with GetSection and GetValue and it works also. But my requirement here is specifically to loop through the list of keys and do some processing on them instead of retrieving the key values with their hardcoded key names which is what happens with GetSection or GetValue

Comment: Why? Are you sure you aren't misunderstanding the Configuration system, trying to use the same way you used ASP.NET's config?

Comment: Whatever you want, you use the `Configutation` object to retrieve those values. There's no other way. There's no need for this either, the Configuration system can already bind those values to concrete objects that can be injected. Or you can pass the IConfiguration object as a dependency through DI.  What are you trying to do, why are you trying to list everything?

Comment: BTW you can use [AsEnumerable()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationextensions.asenumerable?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_ConfigurationExtensions_AsEnumerable_Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_IConfiguration_) to enumerate over all pairs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I edited my question to make it more clear, please have a look.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes this._configuration.GetSection("Section1").AsEnumerable(); indeed works although the first value that it gives has to be ignored because it is a null value; otherwise it pretty much meets my requirement! thanks!

Comment: I agree with @PanagiotisKanavos.  You need to stop thinking in terms of "named-value-pairs" like you did in DotNet-FRAMEWORK.  (and java application.properties).  DotNetCore is about a "configuration POCO, an you are just using json to persist it, and retrieve it.  (and you inject the POCO into the classes that need the information) see : https://stackoverflow.com/a/68414308/214977

Answer (score 2):

I tried Brandon's answer and was having trouble. This is what I came up with:

```
public static void DoSomethingWithConfigurationManager(IConfigurationRoot config)
{
    var section = config.GetSection("exampleSection").GetChildren();
    foreach (var item in section)
    {
        // Do something with item.Key and item.Value
        // You can access lower sections with item.GetChildren() and repeat the process
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will let you iterate over the keys and values within the appsettings file specifically.

```
public static void DoSomethingWithConfigurationManager(IConfiguration config)
{
    var root = config as ConfigurationRoot;
    if (root != null)
    {
        var appSettingsProvider = root.Providers.FirstOrDefault(x => x is JsonConfigurationProvider && ((JsonConfigurationProvider)x).Source?.Path == "appsettings.json") as JsonConfigurationProvider;
        if (appSettingsProvider != null)
        {
            var dataElement = appSettingsProvider.GetType().GetProperty("Data", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            var dataValue = (SortedDictionary<string, string>)dataElement.GetValue(appSettingsProvider);
            foreach (var item in dataValue)
            {
                //Do something with item.Key and item.Value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Kindly be aware that my web application targeting .NET 7

```
IEnumerable<IConfigurationSection> section = config.GetSection("Section1").GetChildren();

foreach (IConfigurationSection item in section)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"Key: {item.Key}; Value:{item.Value}");
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I have used like this in my `program.cs` file and it pick up the value correctly with `appsettings.json` file you can also try like this.

**Program.cs**

```
IHost host = new HostBuilder()            
                 .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, configApp) =>
                 {
                     configApp.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", true);
                     configApp.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", true);
}
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "https_port": 443,
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Comment: That's not what the OP asks

Comment: I thought this was useful for an immediate need so I upvoted.